# Numpy erorr - object too deep for desired array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I was trying to write a code which can find out if the relation between the two variables is a Sigmoid relation, a quadratic relation or a linear relation.
But I am facing this error-

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-0aa6b9186fbb> in <module>
      3 for columns in x_train.columns:
      4     X_value = x_train[columns]
----> 5     ppot_Quad,pcov_Quad = curve_fit(Quadratic_Relation,X_value.values,y_train.values)
      6     ppot_sig,pcov_sig =  curve_fit(sigmoid,X_value,y_train)
      7     ppot_Exp,ppcov_Exp = curve_fit(Exponential_Relation,X_value,y_train)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    749         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    750         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 751         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    752         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    753         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    391             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
    392         with _MINPACK_LOCK:
--> 393             retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
    394                                      gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    395     else:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Here's my code-

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import sklearn.metrics as sm
for columns in x_train.columns:
    X_value = x_train[columns]
    ppot_Quad,pcov_Quad = curve_fit(Quadratic_Relation,X_value.values,y_train.values)
    ppot_sig,pcov_sig =  curve_fit(sigmoid,X_value,y_train)
    ppot_Exp,ppcov_Exp = curve_fit(Exponential_Relation,X_value,y_train)
    regr_poly =  Polynomial_Relation(X_value)
    regr_Linear =  Polynomial_Relation(X_Value)
    accuracy_dict = {}
    X_test_value =  x_test[[columns]]
    accuracy_dict["Quadratic"] = sm.r2_score(Quadratic_Relation(X_test_value,*ppot_Quad),y_test)
    accuracy_dict["Sigmoid"] = sm.r2_score(sigmoid(X_test_value,*ppot_sig),y_test)
    accuracy_dict["Exponential"] =  sm.r2_score(Exponential_Relation(X_test_value,*ppot_Exp),y_test)
    accuracy_dict["Polynomial"] =  accuracy_dict["Polynomial"] =  sm.r2_score(regr_poly.predict(X_test_value),y_test)
    accuracy_dict["Linear"] =  sm.r2_score(regr_poly.predict(X_test_value),y_test)
```

Comment: Do a search on `[scipy] too deep`. This `too deep` has come up many times with scipy `curve_fit`.  Usually the problem is the dimensionalty of the arrays, but I'll let you decjde which is most relevant.

Comment: Make sure that thecarguments to `curve_fit` match the documented ones with regard to dimensions and dtype.  The error occurs in fast compiled `minpac` function, which is not very forgiving in these matters.

Comment: On line 15, I think there is a typo as `accuracy_dict["Polynomial"]` is called two times.

Comment: See recent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69238333/fit-a-differential-equation-using-scipy-getting-object-too-deep-for-desired-ar, where the `to deep` is the result of curve_fit function producing a (n,1) result, when it should just be (n,), matching the `ydata` shape.