# Fit a differential equation using scipy, getting "object too deep for desired array"

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I'm trying to fit a curve to a differential equation. For the sake of simplicity, I'm just doing the logistic equation here. I wrote the code below but I get an error shown below it. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as optim
from scipy.integrate import odeint

df_yeast = pd.DataFrame({'cd': [9.6, 18.3, 29., 47.2, 71.1, 119.1, 174.6, 257.3, 350.7, 441., 513.3, 559.7, 594.8, 629.4, 640.8, 651.1, 655.9, 659.6], 'td': np.arange(18)})

N0 = 1
parsic = [5, 2]

def logistic_de(t, N, r, K):
    return r*N*(1 - N/K)

def logistic_solution(t, r, K):
    return odeint(logistic_de, N0, t, (r, K))

params, _ = optim.curve_fit(logistic_solution, df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'], p0=parsic);
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-2a5a467cfa43> in <module>
----> 1 params, _ = optim.curve_fit(logistic_solution, df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'], p0=parsic);

~/SageMath/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    782         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    783         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 784         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    785         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    786         ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

~/SageMath/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    420         if maxfev == 0:
    421             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
--> 422         retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
    423                                  gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    424     else:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Comment: While `curve_fit` tries to convert the inputs to arrays, when you have problems like this, do the conversion beforehand, e.g. `df.to_numpy()` etc, and make sure that the resulting arrays match the documented requirements, especially with regard to dimension and dtype.

Comment: Just the other day, a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231675/numpy-erorr-object-too-deep-for-desired-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hpaulj has pointed out the problem with the shape of the return value from `logistic_solution` and shown that fixing that eliminates the error that you reported.

There is, however, another problem in the code.  The problem does not generate an error, but it does result in an incorrect solution to your test problem (the logistic differential equation).  By default, `odeint` expects the `t` argument of the function that computes the differential equations to be the *second* argument. Either change the order of the first two arguments of `logistic_de`, or add the argument `tfirst=True` to your call of `odeint`.  The second option is a bit nicer, because it will allow you to use `logistic_de` with `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` if you decide to try that function instead of `odeint`.

Comment: I had no problems running the `odeint`.  The problem is the dimension of `logistic_solution` result compared to the 1d `ydata` - `curve_fit` is the one that's complaining about a `too deep` array.  `too deep` is a particular `scipy` error message that does not immediately translate to a `numpy` dimension issue.

Comment: @hpaulj: Ah, so the mistake that I pointed out was not the source of the error that was reported.  It is, however, still a mistake, and the code as written is not solving the logistic equation!  Look at your plot of the computed solution.  It reaches a maximum at approximately t=15, and then decreases a little.  A solution to the logistic differential equation cannot do that.  Try adding `tfirst=True` to the call of `odeint`.

Answer (score 0):

A sample run of `logistic_solution` produces a (18,1) result:

```
In [268]: logistic_solution(df_yeast['td'], *parsic)
Out[268]: 
array([[ 1.00000000e+00],
       [ 2.66666671e+00],
       [ 4.33333337e+00],
       [ 1.00000004e+00],
       [-1.23333333e+01],
       [-4.06666666e+01],
       [-8.90000000e+01],
       [-1.62333333e+02],
       [-2.65666667e+02],
       [-4.04000000e+02],
       [-5.82333333e+02],
       [-8.05666667e+02],
       [-1.07900000e+03],
       [-1.40733333e+03],
       [-1.79566667e+03],
       [-2.24900000e+03],
       [-2.77233333e+03],
       [-3.37066667e+03]])
In [269]: _.shape
Out[269]: (18, 1)
```

but the `y` values is

```
In [281]: df_yeast['cd'].values.shape
Out[281]: (18,)
```

Define an alternative function that returns a 1d array:

```
In [282]: def foo(t,r,K):
     ...:     return logistic_solution(t,r,K).ravel()
```

This works:

```
In [283]: params, _ = optim.curve_fit(foo, df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'], p0=parsic)
In [284]: params
Out[284]: array([16.65599815, 15.52779946])
```

test the `params`:

```
In [287]: logistic_solution(df_yeast['td'], *params)
Out[287]: 
array([[  1.        ],
       [  8.97044688],
       [ 31.45157847],
       [ 66.2980814 ],
       [111.36464226],
       [164.50594767],
       [223.5766842 ],
       [286.43153847],
       [350.92519706],
       [414.91234658],
       [476.24767362],
       [532.78586477],
       [582.38160664],
       [622.88958582],
       [652.1644889 ],
       [668.0610025 ],
       [668.43381319],
       [651.13760758]])
In [288]: df_yeast['cd'].values
Out[288]: 
array([  9.6,  18.3,  29. ,  47.2,  71.1, 119.1, 174.6, 257.3, 350.7,
       441. , 513.3, 559.7, 594.8, 629.4, 640.8, 651.1, 655.9, 659.6])
```

[image]

`too deep` in this context means a 2d array, when it should be 1d, in order to compare with `ydata`

```
ydata : array_like
    The dependent data, a length M array - nominally ``f(xdata, ...)``.
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't correctly solve the logistic equation. See the answer + comments by @Warren Weckesser. However, it did solve the error. So thank you for that!